# how to remove only one element from array using redux action?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an array of elements with objects and numbers along with operator

Ex: `let a =[‘(‘,’2’,{}]`

The object is being inserted into array through redux action and numbers and operators are through keyboard.

Now, whenever I want to delete an object 9 ‘m calling one more redux action.Whenever I am trying to delete the object through action whole array is getting deleted.

How to delete only object from array?

Comment: Please add the related code.

Answer (score 0):

copy and splice for instance. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your array without object

```
const deleteObject = (array) =>{
 return array.filter(e => typeof(e) !== "Object")
}
```

your action must call the deleteObject function

Answer (score 0):

First remember not to mutate the state.

Second I think you may want to prevent dispatching an action on any other keys which are not meant to be in your array and use back button key to dispatch `DELETE_ACTION`.

```
// your insert action
dispatch({ type: 'INCERT_ACTION', payload: ObjOrString })
// your delete actions
dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_ACTION', payload: ObjOrString })


// your reducer to handle that action
function yourReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCERT_ACTION':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'DELETE_ACTION':
      return state.filter(e => (typeof(e) !== "Object" && whate_ever_condition))
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```